# Take it down or took it down

Tags: grammar, tense

Playing a computer game: Let's say you have just raided(attack) an enemy base, hitting a gold storage with gold in it, but the time **ran out.** Which reaction is correct:

> "Too bad I nearly **take it down**, its a shame coz it is filled with a good deal of resource.''

Or

> "Too bad I nearly **took it down**, its a shame coz it is filled with a good deal of resource."

Is it **time ran out?**(coz it is a past) or **time runs out?**

And is it **take it down** or **took it down**(coz it is also    taken from the past)

Comment: As you say it is in the past, so why do you want to use present tense?

Comment: This means I use present tense to say it is a fact.

Comment: Your example should be two sentences - "Too bad I nearly took it down. It's a shame coz it is filled with a good deal of resource." The second one is a fact but the first one implies you actually did something else (*nearly* implying you almost did it but then did something else).

Comment: You nailed it, I can use this format in future conversation that is why I'm asking this. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your example should be two sentences:

> Too bad I nearly **took it** down. It's a shame coz it is filled with a good deal of resource.

The second sentence is a fact, but the first sentence implies you actually did something else (*nearly* implying you almost took it down but then did something else). This pushes the "taking down" possibility into the past.

As for *time ran out* vs. *time runs out*, it needs to be past tense, because *ran out* my definition means that function (running a timer) has ended.

In the situation where the timer is still running, you would use **time is running out** since the timer is in a changing rather than a steady state.

Comment: Is it 'but the time ran out' or 'but the time runs out'?

Comment: Please check my edit.